# indexOf similar function to return multiple appearance in javascript

Tags: javascript

When using indexOf, I can just locate the position of the first appearance:

for example:

```
a=[1,2,4,2];
b=a.indexOf(2);
alert(b) //returns 1
```

Is there any alternative function to indexOf to find the both position or am I missing something? I am looking for the shortcut. Of course, I can always go for writing a simple look to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With one loop :

```
function indexesOf(arr, target) {
    let index = [];
    // For each element, index pushed in index[]
    arr.forEach((el, i) => {
        if (el === target) index.push(i)
    });
    return index;
}
alert(indexesOf([1, 2, 4, 2], 2));  // -> 1, 3
```

With two loops :

```
function indexesOf(arr, target) {
  // Map matching elements to their index, and others to null.
  return arr.map(function (el, i) { return (el === target) ? i : null; })
            // Throw out the nulls.
            .filter(function (x) { return x !== null; });
}

alert(indexesOf([1, 2, 4, 2], 2));  // -> 1, 3
```

Comment: Note: what this won't do is find the indexes of `NaN` in an array, if that is what you require from the function, so you would need an alternative comparison method rather than `===`

Comment: @Xotic750, It's exactly like `Array.prototype.indexOf` in that manner.  Section [15.4.4.14 / 9 b ii](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.14) says that `indexOf` uses the *strict equality algorithm* which uses the usual semantics for NaN equality.

Comment: Yes, I was just making a note in case someone tried to use it for such and then wondered why it didn't work. :)

Answer (score 5):

indexOf takes a second argument (the starting index)

So `a.indexOf(2,2)` would give you 3

To generalize, if `x = a.indexOf(2)`, then the next instance is `a.indexOf(2, x+1)`

Answer (score 1):

As you are using a recent ECMAScript 5 method then you may want to consider using [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) along with a new Harmony proposed method [`Object.is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is)

Javascript

```
var func = {}.is,
    is;

if (typeof func === "function") {
    is = func;
} else {
    is = function is(x, y) {
        if (x === y) {
            if (x === 0) {
                return 1 / x === 1 / y;
            }

            return true;
        }

        var x1 = x,
            y1 = y;

        return x !== x1 && y !== y1;
    };
}

function indexesOf(array, value) {
    if (!Array.isArray(array)) {
        throw new TypeError("First attribute must be an array.");
    }

    return array.map(function (element, index) {
        if (is(value, element)) {
            return index;
        }
    }).filter(function (element) {
        return typeof element === "number";
    });
}

var test = [1, 2, 4, 2];

console.log(indexesOf(test, 2));
```

Output

```
[1, 3]
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/bFwmD/)

***Update:*** I have been castigated in the past for using loops when people have the strong belief "but this is exactly what these new methods are designed for". So, I am going to present alternative single loop solutions too.

**ECMAScript 5 [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)**

Javascript

```
function indexesOf(array, value) {
    if (!Array.isArray(array)) {
        throw new TypeError("First attribute must be an array.");
    }

    return array.reduce(function (previous, current, index) {
        if (is(value, current)) {
            previous.push(index);
        }

        return previous;
    }, []);
}
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Pgb9S/)

**ECMAScript 5 [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach)**

Javascript

```
function indexesOf(array, value) {
    if (!Array.isArray(array)) {
        throw new TypeError("First attribute must be an array.");
    }

    var indexes = [];

    array.forEach(function (element, index) {
        if (is(value, element)) {
            indexes.push(index);
        }
    });

    return indexes.
}
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/EHVhL/)

**ECMAScript 5 [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexof)**

*Note: this method is unable to find the indexes of* `NaN`

*Could also use `Array.lastIndexOf` and work in reverse*

Javascript

```
function indexesOf(array, value) {
    if (!Array.isArray(array)) {
        throw new TypeError("First attribute must be an array.");
    }

    var index = array.indexOf(value),
        indexes = [];

    while (index !== -1) {
        indexes.push(index);
        index = array.indexOf(value, index + 1);
    }

    return indexes;
}
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/aTNWJ/)

**standard [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)**

Javascript

```
function indexesOf(array, value) {
    if ({}.toString.call(array) !== "[object Array]") {
        throw new TypeError("First attribute must be an array.");
    }

    var indexes = [],
        length,
        index;

    for (index = 0, length = array.length; index < length; index += 1) {
        if (array.hasOwnProperty(index) && is(value, array[index])) {
            indexes.push(index);
        }
    }

    return indexes;
}
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/rVVmA/)

**Standard [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while)**

Javascript

```
function indexesOf(array, value) {
    if ({}.toString.call(array) !== "[object Array]") {
        throw new TypeError("First attribute must be an array.");
    }

    var length = array.length,
        indexes = []
        index = 0;

    while (index < length) {
        if (array.hasOwnProperty(index) && is(value, array[index])) {
            indexes.push(index);
        }

        index += 1;
    }

    return indexes;
}
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/y7PHT/)

**Standard [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)**

*Note: This is NOT recommended, but should be fine.*

[Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

Javascript

```
function indexesOf(array, value) {
    if ({}.toString.call(array) !== "[object Array]") {
        throw new TypeError("First attribute must be an array.");
    }

    var indexes = [],
        prop;

    for (prop in array) {
        if (array.hasOwnProperty(prop) && is(+prop, prop >>> 0) && is(value, array[prop])) {
            indexes.push(+prop);
        }
    }

    return indexes;
}
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/8fPmp/)

*Note: All of the solutions here handle both dense and sparse arrays.*

And finally a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/battle-of-indexesof/2) comparing all of these solutions.

Comment: This was really a good alternative answer. I would also like to know the reason for downvote.

Answer (score 0):

lastIndexOf() gives the index of last occurence.

But if want an array of indices containing all the occurences of a particular element(2 in your case), you have to write a loop.